# Weights in tensorflow model don't seem to change when printed

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to print weights before and after training in Tensorflow. I'm confused about what I get because weights don't seem to change even if training shows a decreasing cost. My code is:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import argparse

# Import MNIST data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
batch_size = 100
display_step = 1

load = False
max_epochs = 5
training_epochs = max_epochs

# Instantiate saver
if not load:
    # tf Graph Input
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name='x') # mnist data image of shape 28*28=784
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], name='y') # 0-9 digits recognition => 10 classes

    # Set model weights
    W = tf.get_variable('W', initializer=tf.random_normal((784,10), seed=0))
    b = tf.get_variable('b',[10],initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)

    # Construct model
    #pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b,name='pred') # Softmax
    pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W),name='pred') # Softmax

    # Minimize error using cross entropy
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y*tf.log(pred), reduction_indices=1))
    # Gradient Descent
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    # In order to be able to easily retrieve variables and ops later,
    # we add them to collections
    tf.add_to_collection('train_op', optimizer)
    tf.add_to_collection('cost_op', cost)
    tf.add_to_collection('input', x)
    tf.add_to_collection('target', y)
    tf.add_to_collection('pred', pred)

    initial_epoch = 0
else:
    # Find last executed epoch
    from glob import glob
    history = list(map(lambda x: int(x.split('-')[1][:-5]), glob('model.ckpt-*.meta')))
    last_epoch = np.max(history)
    # Instantiate saver object using previously saved meta-graph
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model.ckpt-{}.meta'.format(last_epoch))
    initial_epoch = last_epoch + 1


# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    if not load:
        sess.run(init)
    else:
        saver.restore(sess, 'model.ckpt-{}'.format(last_epoch))
        optimizer = tf.get_collection('train_op')[0]
        cost = tf.get_collection('cost_op')[0]
        x = tf.get_collection('input')[0]
        y = tf.get_collection('target')[0]
        pred = tf.get_collection('pred')[0]

    print ("Variables before training")
    for var in tf.global_variables():
        print (var.name, sess.run(var))

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(initial_epoch, training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_xs,
                                                        y: batch_ys})
            # Compute average loss
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
        # Display logs per epoch step
        if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
        saver.save(sess, './model.ckpt', global_step=epoch)

    print("Optimization Finished!")

    # Test model
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    # Calculate accuracy
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))

    print ("Variables after training")
    for var in tf.global_variables():
        print (var.name, sess.run(var))
```

Before training, printing variables shows something like that for W:

```
W:0 [[-0.22279324  0.75145274  0.30694658 ... -0.20406865 -0.10345581
0.47926915]
....
```

After training, printing produces the same result for W even if cost has decreased from 2.2 to 0.7. Where is my error?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Alex but how can you explain decreasing cost while training if W doesn' change?

Comment: My best guess would be that a persistent reference to its initial value is stored outside the loop; having just copied the code above (with random constants in place of the placeholders), the value of W printed does change after training

Comment: Could you share your code? I tried myself with get_variable and W still doesn't seem to change.

Comment: When I was testing how w printed, I used your code above, with the only change being to make x and y random constants.  I used the same print statement as you did, before training and after

Comment: But you have a training cycle right?

Comment: I edited my code to include all stuff including training cycle. Can you try it and tell me if W changes after training?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your weight has changed in your training. I'm not sure but I think you didn't see it because you just printed out parts of the weight and found that those parts are the same. I changed your code a little bit to add `numpy.array_equal` comparison and add checking in the training loop as follow:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import argparse

# Import MNIST data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
batch_size = 100
display_step = 1

load = False
max_epochs = 5
training_epochs = max_epochs

# Instantiate saver
if not load:
    # tf Graph Input
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name='x') # mnist data image of shape 28*28=784
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], name='y') # 0-9 digits recognition => 10 classes

    # Set model weights
    W = tf.get_variable('W', initializer=tf.random_normal((784,10), seed=0))
    b = tf.get_variable('b',[10],initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)

    # Construct model
    #pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b,name='pred') # Softmax
    pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W),name='pred') # Softmax

    # Minimize error using cross entropy
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y*tf.log(pred), reduction_indices=1))
    # Gradient Descent
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    # In order to be able to easily retrieve variables and ops later,
    # we add them to collections
    tf.add_to_collection('train_op', optimizer)
    tf.add_to_collection('cost_op', cost)
    tf.add_to_collection('input', x)
    tf.add_to_collection('target', y)
    tf.add_to_collection('pred', pred)

    initial_epoch = 0
else:
    # Find last executed epoch
    from glob import glob
    history = list(map(lambda x: int(x.split('-')[1][:-5]), glob('model.ckpt-*.meta')))
    last_epoch = np.max(history)
    # Instantiate saver object using previously saved meta-graph
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('model.ckpt-{}.meta'.format(last_epoch))
    initial_epoch = last_epoch + 1


# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    if not load:
        sess.run(init)
    else:
        saver.restore(sess, 'model.ckpt-{}'.format(last_epoch))
        optimizer = tf.get_collection('train_op')[0]
        cost = tf.get_collection('cost_op')[0]
        x = tf.get_collection('input')[0]
        y = tf.get_collection('target')[0]
        pred = tf.get_collection('pred')[0]

    print ("Variables before training")
    old_var = {}
    for var in tf.global_variables():
        old_var[var.name] = sess.run(var)
        #print (var.name, sess.run(var))
    print(old_var)
    new_var = {}

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(initial_epoch, training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_xs,
                                                        y: batch_ys})
            # Compute average loss
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
        # Display logs per epoch step
        if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
        print('Check variable changes')
        for var in tf.global_variables():
            new_var[var.name] = sess.run(var)
        for vname in new_var:
            eq = np.array_equal(old_var[vname], new_var[vname])
            print('Is {} changed? {}'.format(vname, not eq))
            if not eq:
                old_var[vname] = new_var[vname]
        saver.save(sess, './model.ckpt', global_step=epoch)

    print("Optimization Finished!")

    # Test model
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    # Calculate accuracy
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))

    print ("Variables after training")
    for var in tf.global_variables():
        new_var[var.name] = sess.run(var)
        #print (var.name, sess.run(var))
    print(new_var)

    print('Check variable changes')
    for vname in new_var:
        eq = np.array_equal(old_var[vname], new_var[vname])
        print('Is {} changed? {}'.format(vname, not eq))
```

The most relevant section of my output is:

```
Epoch: 0001 cost= 7.935980950
Check variable changes
Is W:0 changed? True
Is b:0 changed? False
Epoch: 0002 cost= 4.306569523
Check variable changes
Is W:0 changed? True
Is b:0 changed? False
Epoch: 0003 cost= 3.009391170
Check variable changes
Is W:0 changed? True
Is b:0 changed? False
Epoch: 0004 cost= 2.379378949
Check variable changes
Is W:0 changed? True
Is b:0 changed? False
Epoch: 0005 cost= 2.014794181
Check variable changes
Is W:0 changed? True
Is b:0 changed? False
Optimization Finished!
```

Your bias doesn't change as expected. If you run it, you will also find that your after training weight is the same as the weight from the your last epoch.

Comment: Thanks @Y. Luo you're right. Do you have an explanation for b not changing?

Comment: 'pred' does not include b, so there is no gradient from loss to b.  You'd see b change as well if you used the 'pred' term that included bias (the one which is currently commented out)

Comment: Thanks, @Alex. That's why I said "as expected". Your plotting is also very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Y. Lou is correct, your W value actually *is* changing.  It's not very visible in part because the values you see when printing W are the corners and edges (the parts which change least).  I added some plotting that shows how the absolute difference between W and the initial W, with epochs on the vertical and digits on the horizontal; more intense color corresponds to a greater difference.

Note that the upper left corners and the bottom right corners have almost no change (oftentimes literally *zero* change); these are the values you see when printing (an abridged summary of) W, and it explains why it never seems to change.  This all makes sense because the corner pixels are almost never useful when predicting digit class.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Import MNIST data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.01
batch_size = 100
display_step = 1

load = False
max_epochs = 5
training_epochs = max_epochs

# Instantiate saver
if not load:
    # tf Graph Input
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name='x') # mnist data image of shape 28*28=784
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], name='y') # 0-9 digits recognition => 10 classes

    # Set model weights
    W = tf.get_variable('W', initializer=tf.random_normal((784,10), seed=0))

    # Construct model
    pred = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W),name='pred') # Softmax

    # Minimize error using cross entropy
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y*tf.log(pred), reduction_indices=1))
    # Gradient Descent
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
    train_oper=optimizer.minimize(cost)

    print(optimizer.compute_gradients(cost))

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    # In order to be able to easily retrieve variables and ops later,
    # we add them to collections
    tf.add_to_collection('train_op', train_oper)
    tf.add_to_collection('cost_op', cost)
    tf.add_to_collection('input', x)
    tf.add_to_collection('target', y)
    tf.add_to_collection('pred', pred)

    initial_epoch = 0

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    print ("Variables before training")
    for var in tf.get_default_graph().get_collection('trainable_variables'):
        print (var, sess.run(var))

    #Initial value of W
    W_0=W.eval(sess)
    # Training cycle
    diff=[]
    for epoch in range(initial_epoch, training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c = sess.run([train_oper, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_xs,
                                                        y: batch_ys})
            # Compute average loss
            avg_cost += c/total_batch
        #Calculate difference between current W and initial W
        diff.append(np.reshape(np.abs(W_0-sess.run(W)),(28,28,10)))
        # Display logs per epoch step
        if (epoch+1) % display_step == 0:
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost))
        saver.save(sess, './model.ckpt', global_step=epoch)

    print("Optimization Finished!")

    # Test model
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    # Calculate accuracy
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels}))

    print ("Variables after training")
    for var in tf.get_default_graph().get_collection('trainable_variables'):
        print (var, sess.run(var))


    scale=np.max(diff)
    fig,axs=plt.subplots(len(diff),10)   
    for i in range(len(diff)):
        for j in range(10):
            axs[i][j].imshow(diff[i][:,:,j]/scale,vmin=0,vmax=1)
            axs[i][j].axis('off') 
    plt.show(fig)
```

Comment: Thanks @Alex I accepted the answer from Y.Luo because he was the first to point to the explanation. Your help and your code for visualizing the changes are also very appreciated though.